# Determine advised Spring proxy at runtime?

Tags: spring, aop

How does one determine the underlying class at runtime (in my case in a debugger) for a class that has been proxied by Spring AOP as a JDK dynamic proxy?

[EDIT]

After a bit of searching, and this solution is Spring-specific, you can do the following:

```
final TargetClassAware advised = (TargetClassAware) foo;
System.err.println("Advised: " + advised.getTargetClass());
```